# Is there a way in rails to intercept controller requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, interceptor

I don't think Rails calls it an interceptor, but I don't know what to search for.

In Java/Spring, you can create Interceptors that are called before and after any controller action in the MVC framework. This makes it easy to add data to the model for every request, so you don't have to keep adding it to each of your 50 controllers.

I have to take a wild guess and say Rails has something to do achieve the same effect... but I have no idea what it is called.

Care to share? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Filters.

- [ActionController::Filters::ClassMethods](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)
- [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Comment: Thanks! I can take it from here ;)